# How to find what item exaclty checked in CheckBoxList

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

I have 2 side-by-side CheckBoxList. My purpose is when I check one item in List1, I add that item to the second list. Below is the code I have written.

The problem is it always adds the first item I selected.

```
protected void lbxSource_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListItem itm = lbxSource.SelectedItem;
    ListItem newItem = new ListItem(itm.Text, itm.Value);
    lbTrg.Items.Add(newItem);
}
```

Actually in the event, I don't know how to get what item I checked last time.

Comment: The problems lies with the fact that you have written the listbox binding code directly inside the page_load event. Wrap that code inside if(!Page.IsPostBack) condition. That will solve your issue of adding first item always.

Comment: That's not the case. I populate the first list in "if (!Page.IsPostBack)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If after adding the item to the second list, you clear selected items in the first list, the next time you get the exact checked item in the event.

```
protected void lbxSource_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListItem itm = lbxSource.SelectedItem;
    ListItem newItem = new ListItem(itm.Text, itm.Value);
    lbTrg.Items.Add(newItem);
    lbxSource.ClearSelection(); // This line is the answer to your question
}
```

Hope this helps. I had exactly the same case a few weeks ago :)

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over all the selected items, and if the item is NOT in the second list add it.

```
foreach (ListItem li in lbxSource.Items)
{
    if (li.Selected)
    {
        // remove/add...
    }
}
```